# Executor/Queue process last known task only

Tags: java, concurrency, queue, executorservice

I'm looking to write some concurrent code which will process an event. This processing can take a long time.

Whilst that event is processing it should record incoming events and then process the last incoming events when it is free to run again. (The other events can be thrown away). This is a little bit like a FILO queue but I only need to store one element in the queue.

Ideally I would like to plug in my new Executor into my event processing architecture shown below.

```
public class AsyncNode<I, O> extends AbstractNode<I, O>  {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AsyncNode.class);
    private Executor executor;

    public AsyncNode(EventHandler<I, O> handler, Executor executor) {
        super(handler);
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    @Override
    public void emit(O output) {
        if (output != null) {
            for (EventListener<O> node : children) {
                node.handle(output);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(final I input) {

        executor.execute(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                emit(handler.process(input));
                }catch (Exception e){
                    log.error("Exception occured whilst processing input." ,e);
                    throw e;
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

}

Comment: Do you want this executor to process other tasks submitted to it normally? Or will this executor only be used to process your events?

Comment: It should always execute the latest known task and ignore intermediate tasks which have been queued but not executed. I've put forward my solution but haven't tested it yet.

Comment: That then means the executor is actively executing only one task at a time irrespective of how many threads you launched the executor with?

Comment: I dont think thats true....if you have a task which never finishes so the first thread is always busy....the next thread in the thread pool will pick up the next incoming task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class LatestTaskExecutor implements Executor {
    private final AtomicReference<Runnable> lastTask =new AtomicReference<>();
    private final Executor executor;

    public LatestTaskExecutor(Executor executor) {
        super();
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable command) {
        lastTask.set(command);
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Runnable task=lastTask.getAndSet(null);
                if(task!=null){
                    task.run();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}

@RunWith( MockitoJUnitRunner.class )
public class LatestTaskExecutorTest {

    @Mock private Executor executor;
    private LatestTaskExecutor latestExecutor;
    @Before
    public void setup(){
        latestExecutor=new LatestTaskExecutor(executor);
    }
    @Test
    public void testRunSingleTask() {
        Runnable run=mock(Runnable.class);
        latestExecutor.execute(run);
        ArgumentCaptor<Runnable> captor=ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Runnable.class);
        verify(executor).execute(captor.capture());
        captor.getValue().run();
        verify(run).run();
    }

    @Test
    public void discardsIntermediateUpdates(){
        Runnable run=mock(Runnable.class);
        Runnable run2=mock(Runnable.class);
        latestExecutor.execute(run);
        latestExecutor.execute(run2);
        ArgumentCaptor<Runnable> captor=ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Runnable.class);
        verify(executor,times(2)).execute(captor.capture());
        for (Runnable runnable:captor.getAllValues()){
            runnable.run();
        }
        verify(run2).run();
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(run);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will silently drop submitted Runnables, which could cause trouble if you are waiting on the associated Futures (you would want them canceled). I would recommend James Mudd’s answer.

Comment: Actually so does the DiscardOldestPolicy in James Mudd’s answer. Workaround here (not my blog): http://www.concurrentaffair.org/2012/10/27/problems-with-rejectedexecutionhandler-and-futures/

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't do either. I would have an AtomicReference to the event you want to process and add a task to process it in a destructive way.

```
final AtomicReference<Event> eventRef =

public void processEvent(Event event) {
   eventRef.set(event);
   executor.submit(new Runnable() {
       public vodi run() {
           Event e = eventRef.getAndSet(null);
           if (e == null) return;
           // process event
       }
   }
}
```

This will only ever process the next event when the executor is free, without customising the executor or queue (which can be used for other things)

This also scales to having keyed events i.e. you want to process the last event for a key.

Comment: I was thinking of wrapping an Executor implementation around this so I can reuse the Executor for different scenarios without having to write any code. I need to do this fairly often for different event types and different processing.

Comment: For different types you could have a map of EventType to AtomicReference values.

Comment: I think what I meant to say is that I want to separate this logic from the processing logic completely.

Comment: I have posted some code above which shows my event processing code. I would like to create an Executor so that the event processing code remains the same but it only ever processes the latest update and discards the rest. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

I think the key to this is the "discard policy" you need to apply to your `Executor`. If you only want to handle the latest task then you need a queue size of one and a "discarding policy" of throw away the oldest. Here is an example of an Executor that will do this

```
Executor latestTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, // Single threaded 
        30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, // Keep alive, not really important here
        new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1), // Single element queue
        new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy()); // When new work is submitted discard oldest
```

Then when your tasks come in just submit them to this executor, if there is already a queued job it will be replaced with the new one

```
latestTaskExecutor.execute(() -> doUpdate()));
```

Here is a example app showing this working

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class LatestUpdate {

    private static final Executor latestTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, // Single threaded
            30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, // Keep alive, not really important here
            new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1), // Single element queue
            new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy()); // When new work is submitted discard oldest

    private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private static final Random random = new Random(); 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LatestUpdate latestUpdate = new LatestUpdate();
        latestUpdate.run();
    }

    private void doUpdate(int number) {
        System.out.println("Latest number updated is: " + number);
        try { // Wait a random amount of time up to 5 seconds. Processing the update takes time...
            Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(5000));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void run() {
        // Updates a counter every second and schedules an update event
        Thread counterUpdater = new Thread(() -> {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000L); // Wait one second
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                counter.incrementAndGet();
                // Schedule this update will replace any existing update waiting 
                latestTaskExecutor.execute(() -> doUpdate(counter.get()));
                System.out.println("New number is: " + counter.get());
            }
        });
        counterUpdater.start(); // Run the thread
    }
}
```

This also covers the case for GUIs where once updates stop arriving you want the GUI to become eventually consistent with the last event received.

Comment: If this does not block the calling thread, this looks like the best answer.

Comment: That's correct this approach does **not** block the calling thread.

Comment: This will silently drop submitted Runnables, which could cause trouble if you are waiting on the associated Futures (you would want them canceled). Workaround here (not my blog): http://www.concurrentaffair.org/2012/10/27/problems-with-rejectedexecutionhandler-and-futures/

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a modified version of the one from DD which minimzes submission of superfluous tasks.

An [atomic reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) is used to keep track of the latest event. A custom task is submitted to the queue for potentially processing an event, only the task that gets to read the latest event actually goes ahead and does useful work before clearing out the atomic reference to null. When other tasks get a chance to run and find no event is available to process, they just do nothing and pass away silently. Submitting superfluous tasks are avoided by tracking the number of available tasks in the queue. If there is at least one task pending in the queue, we can avoid submitting the task as the event will be handled when an already queued task is dequeued.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class EventExecutorService implements Executor {

    private final Executor executor;
    // the field which keeps track of the latest available event to process
    private final AtomicReference<Runnable> latestEventReference = new AtomicReference<>();
    private final AtomicInteger activeTaskCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public EventExecutorService(final Executor executor) {
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(final Runnable eventTask) {
        // update the latest event
        latestEventReference.set(eventTask);
        // read count _after_ updating event
        final int activeTasks = activeTaskCount.get();

        if (activeTasks == 0) {
            // there is definitely no other task to process this event, create a new task
            final Runnable customTask = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // decrement the count for available tasks _before_ reading event
                    activeTaskCount.decrementAndGet();
                    // find the latest available event to process
                    final Runnable currentTask = latestEventReference.getAndSet(null);
                    if (currentTask != null) {
                        // if such an event exists, process it
                        currentTask.run();
                    } else {
                        // somebody stole away the latest event. Do nothing.
                    }
                }
            };
            // increment tasks count _before_ submitting task
            activeTaskCount.incrementAndGet();
            // submit the new task to the queue for processing
            executor.execute(customTask);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this guilty of pre-optimization?

Comment: @DD. Its based on the info that tasks are long running and potentially quite a few events will be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Though I like James Mudd's solution but it still enqueues a second task while previous is running which might be undesirable. If you want to always ignore/discard arriving task if previous is not completed you can make some wrapper like this:

```
public class DiscardingSubmitter {
private final ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
private Future<?> future = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null); //to avoid null check

public void submit(Runnable r){
    if (future.isDone()) {
        future = es.submit(r);
    }else {
        //Task skipped, log if you want
    }
}
```

}